# The input is not a valid Base-64 string from StreamReader

Tags: c#, encryption

I'm getting an encrypted string from an API server

```
try
{
    HttpWebRequest _request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url);
    _request.KeepAlive = false;

    using (HttpWebResponse _response = (HttpWebResponse)_request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream _stream = _response.GetResponseStream())
        {

            using (StreamReader _reader = new StreamReader(_stream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                string _content = _reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(Decrypt(_content.ToString(), _key, _iv));
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

But I'm getting an error:

> System.FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it
>   contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or
>   an illegal character among the padding characters.

The weird thing is that if I copy the string that is returned it Decrypts fine:

```
string str = "jcXddetnrE6ujO/Al1pqSRPK1+JXfal1XgANOsojPV9SUMOjnBgW09AacxhOUGYWZQoUlfsTEk/8Al1NuX/Gk/S2utUCLeEqHLrXwP5tkFgrrqUffHOzxWyD5vwIY2zQ";
Console.WriteLine(Decrypt(str, _key, _iv));
```

Does the string from the StreamReader have to be converted somehow?

Comment: Where this string coming from? Any chance it contains quotes that have been removed when you copied it? Try to print the encrypted string to the console

Comment: Are you sure the response is coming back in utf-8?

Comment: Its a web based API, so the format is `<response>encryptedkeystring</response>`

Comment: If it's coming back as xml, you'll need to extract the string from the rest of the xml. That's not what you're testing in the second bit of code.

Comment: Please re-read [MCVE] guidance. Code sample should include all data inline if possible. (I.e. it seem like in this case constant value would demonstrate problem better than `string _content = _reader.ReadToEnd();` )

Comment: Yes! it was coming back with quotes. A simple `.Trim` fixes the issue, though I should just parse it as xml etc.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the issue is how `_content` comes in and that as a constant it works. So I'm not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: So you are saying that when you run the code you get value of `_content` to be `"jcXddetnrE6uj...` and it fails but when you use exactly the same value as constant it passes? I seriously doubt it is the case (and your other comments seem to hint that value of `_content` is actually different than you showed in `str="jC...`)

Comment: Welp that was the question: why these two seemingly same values are clearly NOT the same since one throws an error. Seems like no one else had problems understanding the question.

Comment: @yonisha please put you comment as an answer and I will accept. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The weird thing is that if I copy the string that is returned it Decrypts fine

Make sure to remove leading and trailing quotes and whitespaces before decrypting. Those probably have been removed when you manually copied the string.